# SessionScoped Bean loses data on post-back on Google Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf-2

I use Eclipse 3.7 GAE pluggin for development.  My application uses JSF and datastore, and was set up as per https://sites.google.com/a/wildstartech.com/adventures-in-java/Java-Platform-Enterprise-Edition/JavaServer-Faces/javaserver-faces-20/configuring-javaserver-faces-20-to-run-on-the-google-appengine.  In my development system, it works well.  But when deployed to GAE, the SessionScoped Bean loses data on post-back:

```
// Input facelet
<h:outputLabel for="popupCal">Date </h:outputLabel> 
<p:calendar value="#{editEntry.current.date1}" id="popupCal" />
<h:outputLabel for="code">Code </h:outputLabel> 
<h:inputText id="code" value="#{editEntry.current.accountCode}"/>
<h:outputLabel for="amt">Amount </h:outputLabel> 
<h:inputText id="amt" value="#{editEntry.current.amountInDollars}"/>
<h:commandButton action="#{editEntry.createCashExpenditure}" value="Create Entry"/>


@ManagedBean(name="editEntry")
@SessionScoped
public class EditEntry extends AbstractEntryBean implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(value="#{sessionBean}")
protected SessionBean sessionBean; 

@ManagedProperty(value="#{dao}")
protected Dao dao;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "dao is null? {0}", dao==null);
    setTran_id(0L);
        entries.clear();
        setCurrent(new Entry());
        getCurrent().clear();
        ...
        this.refreshEntries();
}

public void refreshEntries() {
    entries = dao.getEntries(current.getFinyr(), getTran_id());
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.INFO, "entries has {0} items", entries.size());
}

public String createCashExpenditure() {
    if (dao == null) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "dao is null");
        return null;
    }
    entries.clear();
    Entry e = new Entry();
    e.clear();
    e.setAccountCode(current.getAccountCode());
    e.setAccountName(dao.lookupAccoutName(e.getAccountCode()));
    e.setAmount(current.getAmount());
    e.setDate1(current.getDate1());
    e.setTran_id(getTran_id());
    Key key = dao.saveEntry(e, sessionBean.getFinyr());
    e.setId(key.getId());
    entries.add(e);
    current = e;
    this.setTran_id(e.getTran_id());
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.INFO, "current account is: {0}", current.getAccountCode());
    return "newEntry?faces-redirect=true";
}

...
```

}

```
newEntry.xhtml
    <p:dataTable id="items" value="#{editEntry.entries}" var="item">
// editEntry.entries is EMPTY!
```

When EditEntry.createCashExpenditure() is invoked, the log shows EditEntry.current is correctly populated, and saved to the datastore.  Datastore viewer also displays the data.  But on post-back, in newEntry.xhtml facelet, editEntry.entries becomes empty, EditEntry.current loses all data.

I have put in place ForceSessionSerializationPhaseListener as mentioned in http://java.zacheusz.eu/google-app-engine-http-session-vs-jsf-en/394/  The log shows this listener is invoked.

In web.xml, javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE is Production,

Comment: Please investigate the session cookie traffic and report the findings.

Comment: Nothing special.  On first visit, I got JSESSIONID; after logging in with a gmail account, I got ACSID too.  The values and expiry dates of two cookies remain the same before and after the business method createCashExpenditure.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issues, after redirect, previous session is gone.  It only happen when deploy online.

I think that is due to session variable set to 'client' for javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD (in web.xml)

so before redirect, I need explicit set the session as below:

```
getSessionScope().put(sessionname,sessionObj);

public Map getSessionScope() {
  return getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
}
```